# backbone.js - How are models/views linked to DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js

I'm just playing around with backbone.js and some jQuery magic to prepare for some upcoming projects.

One test case contains a table whose rows are rendered by a backbone view. They get perfectly re-rendered on value change. Afterwards the whole table is sorted by an jQuery plugin (Animated Table Sort), rows move to new positions. In fact, this process works once, but the next time, rows appear twice, everything ends up in chaos.

Is it possible, that the link between DOM element and backbone view can't handle such an change? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

When you're developing with a Model/View framework like backbone.js or knockout.js, I find that you need to re-arrange your thinking and implementations to make changes to what is diplayed (like sorting) to the Model, and not allow them to happen in the view (like using a jquery plugin).

If you do end up using a view-side script to do something fancy (animations are a good example), then it is up to you to make sure the model is updated correctly, either by disabling or extending the binding.

Also note that according to the [documentation](http://mitya.co.uk/scripts/Table-sort---now-REGEXP-friendly-111#part3), that animated sort plugin removes your table rows from the DOM, adds them to new DIVs, animates them, removes them from the DIVs, and restores them to the table. I'm wondering if after this is all done, backbone has lost track of those TDs, and when it re-renders after the change, it's just adding a new set since the last set is 'gone'.

Comment: Can you give an example of "disabling or extending the binding" to make sure the model is updated correctly when using a view-side script like a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Disabling would be to stop using backbone for rendering a part of a page. Just use jquery or whatever directly, and forget about binding to your model. Extending would be to make a connector that listend for updates to your model, and then enforces them on your plugin, and similarly listening to you plugins events and making sure that the model is updated with those changes. It can be hard work, especially in the edge cases, and I usually end up just reading the code for the jq plugin, taking out the 'secret sauce' and implementing a plugin for the mvp/mvvm framework.

Comment: "listening to you plugins events and making sure that the model is updated with those changes" -- I've found that to be the easiest thing to do for me. Is that a clean enough solution, or do you think it can cause design problems as the project expands?

Comment: It's totally good enough...if it works. That can depend plugin-to-plugin. Some of them don't have enough eventing to really keep track of their state, but when they do, an event adapter to your MVC framework is the right solution.

Comment: I was mainly concerned about jQuery UI's sortable. Looks like that does have enough eventing to keep track of everything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. Indeed, the table sorter does a lot that makes it difficult fpr backbone to maintain bindings. I've switched over to the great [Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand) which uses a hidden list to animate changes in another (visible) list. Fits better to backbone.js.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection maintains an order for your models, and therefor your corresponding views. If an outside force (like a jQuery table sorting plugin) modifies the order of the views, this change is not inherently reflected in the Backbone collection, so things are quickly out of sync.

Also, if the table sorter clones elements and removes the original, Backbone would likely lose track of the views and end up recreating them.